# How to refer to current file from Integrated Terminal in Visual Studio Code

Tags: terminal, reference, visual-studio-code, built-in

I want to know if it is possible (with a built in variable) to work directly with current file opened in Visual Studio from intergrated terminal, 
for example:

```
>some_command $current_file   (Where $current_file would be a built-in variable that calls the current active file)
```

instead of what I have to do now if terminal is CMD (DOS):

```
> more C:\The\Path\to\File\MyFile.txt
```

Or if the terminal used is bash:

```
$ cat /The/Path/to/File/MyFile.txt
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You could, as a workaround, use the new abilty to send variables like `${file}` to the terminal with such a keybinding (see [vscode docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings)). In your keybindings.json file add:

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+shift+t",
  "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
  "args": { "text": "'${file}'\u000D" }
}
```

Then, in the terminal type `some_command` and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> and the current filename will be appended and the command run.

`\u000D` is a return.

Comment: Thanks Mark for your answer. I was forgot about this question. But I'll have in mind when I need to try

Comment: No problem, this ability just came out this month in an update to vscode.

Comment: Ahhh ok. You are updated about this hehehe. Than you!

Comment: where are these key bindings  defined..?

Comment: @Rohit If you mean like the particular keybinding I showed it goes into your `keybindings.json` file.  Or are you asking where `sendSequence` specifically is documented?

Answer (score 10):

Based on the above answer with activation only when the terminal is in focus:

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+shift+t",
  "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
  "args": { "text": "'${file}'\u000D" },
  "when": "terminalFocus"
}
```