# VSCode integrated terminal argument: current filename

Tags: shell, terminal, visual-studio-code

In VSCode I want to pass the current file name to the integrated terminal
There is a setting:

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe",
```

How can I add the current file name, for example this would be great:

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe %CurrentFileName%",
```

Thanks.

Comment: If you want to use the filename as an argument of a _command_ instead of the whole terminal, see [How to refer to current file from Integrated Terminal in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46004397/711006).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [shell argument](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_shell-arguments) would be in `terminal.integrated.shellArgs.powershell`

Try and use one of the [variables which should be substituted](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_variable-substitution) by their actual value

```
"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.powershell": ["${file}"]
```

Comment: I tried and it does not work for me. As the documentation you referenced states: "VS Code supports variable substitution inside strings _in the tasks.json_ file"; this does not seem to apply to shellArgs. Am I missing something?

Comment: @FrankMonroe You are not missing much, except an issue on the project to request variable substitution takes place *also* in shellArgs ;)

Comment: Thanks - would love to know the issue so I can upvote it.