# Set integrated Terminal name in VSCODE with settings.json

Tags: visual-studio-code

There's a few questions related to renaming or setting a terminal profile:

- [Change Integrated Terminal title in vscode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42898299/1736679)
- [VSCode integrated terminal argument: current filename](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52911479/1736679)

But if you want to define this via settings.json per folder, how would you do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is that it can only be done for the workspace.

- [Ref profile](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_configuring-profiles)
- [Ref settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/multi-root-workspaces#_settings)

Workspace.code-workspace eg:

```json
{
    "settings": {
        "powershell.powerShellDefaultVersion": "PowerShell (x64)",
        "python.envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.venv",
        "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
            "myprofilename": {
                "source": "PowerShell",
                "overrideName": true,
                "icon": "terminal-powershell"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will create the `myprofilename` as a selection for new terminal options.

However, if you want to set the default in a multi root workspace, at a folder level:

eg: somefolder_in_workspace/.vscode/settings.json:

```json
{
  "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "myprofilename"
}
```

You'll see the line greyed out with a message if you hover: `This setting cannot be applied in this workspace. It will be applied when you open the containing workspace folder directly.`

This is how the documentation explains the behaviour:

> To avoid setting collisions, only resource (file, folder) settings are applied when using a multi-root workspace. Settings that affect the entire editor (for example, UI layout) are ignored. For example, two projects cannot both set the zoom level.

So the answer is **no**, for folders in multi root workspaces, but **yes**, if you want the name for the workspace terminal

Comment: There's also a consideration on `.vscode/settings.json` per folder in multi-root: It will only be applied if you are standing on a file opened for that particular folder.